# I'm trying to hit API request from a broadcast receiver, can anyone mention correct way of doing it?

Tags: java, android

public class GetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPrefHelper sharedPrefHelper = new SharedPrefHelper(context);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(1);
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra("result") == "ok") {

            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty(Web.Register.User_Id, sharedPrefHelper.getUserId());
            jsonObject.addProperty(Web.BookingRequest.ACTIVITY, "ok");
            new BasePresenter<>().createApiRequest(BaseApplication.getRetrofit().create(ApisHelper.class)
                    .okResponse(jsonObject), new BaseCallBack<BasicApiModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onCallBack(BasicApiModel output) {
                    if (Log.isLoggable("qwert", Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d("qwert", "Receiver's onCallBack: " + output.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {

             Log.d("qwert", "onReceive: testing_cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

what is the correct way of starting api request from receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't start any long running task in your broadcast receiver, otherwise your app may crash if onReceive runs more than 10 sec. 
It's better to trigger a service from onReceive method and put your network operation inside the service.
Also keep in mind to use intent service / any other service depending on your requirement, with a worker thread to run your network operation so that your UI thread doesn't get blocked.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, actually requirement is to hit api even app is not running in backgroung(killed). will it work?

Comment: Hi can you please explain the actual requirement? Like what is the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: its just like facebook, when a push notification comes facebook give option to like or comment  simillarly my requirement is to click ok button and then hit api that performs a specific network task

Comment: In that case: When you create the notification, attach a pending to your notification to start the service. So when user clicks the button in notification the service will be triggered and put your network operation inside the service .